# checkbox checked with php on page load

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, checked

I am new in programing and stuck at a point. I am using an API which returns multiple values in an array. I get these values in a form which contain check boxes, I just want those check boxes to be checked which have been returned by API. Means it like a ticketing system. For example i have array of seatdata and i want to checked those checkboxes which has id in php array.

```
<?php
$seatdata = array("A1", "A6", "A10","A11");
?>

<table>
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|12' id="A11"   /><label for="A11">A11</label></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|11' id="A10"/> <label for="A10">A10</label></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|10' id="A9" /><label for="A9">A9</label></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|9' id="A8" /><label for="A8">A8</label></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|6' id="A7" /><label for="A7">A7</label></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|5' id="A6" /><label for="A6">A6</label></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|4' id="A5" /><label for="A5">A5</label></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|3' id="A4" ?> /><label for="A4">A4</label></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|2' id="A3" /><label for="A3">A3</label></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|1' id="A2" /><label for="A2">A2</label></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|0' id="A1"/><label for="A1">A1</label></td>
</tr>
```

I have also tried below code but its not working

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="javascript">

var data = ["A1", "A6", "A10","A11"];

$.each(data,function(i,v){

$('#'+v).prop('checked',true)

});

</script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|12' id="A11" />
  <label for="A11">A11</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|11' id="A10" />
  <label for="A10">A10</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|10' id="A9" />
  <label for="A9">A9</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|9' id="A8" />
  <label for="A8">A8</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|6' id="A7" />
  <label for="A7">A7</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|5' id="A6" />
  <label for="A6">A6</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|4' id="A5" />
  <label for="A5">A5</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|3' id="A4" />
  <label for="A4">A4</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|2' id="A3" />
  <label for="A3">A3</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|1' id="A2" />
  <label for="A2">A2</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|0' id="A1" />
  <label for="A1">A1</label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: without anything to work on SO people can only guess.. add all relevant code to OP..add what you have tried so far

Comment: I have added the code @guradio

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oze3m9ez/)

Comment: by not working what do you mean?if you look at the demo the input with those `ID` are `checked`

Comment: thanks @guardio for your help but please see code which i am trying to run but unable to do so

Comment: that is the exact code in the demo i gave did you check the checkbox?they are checked what do you expect?

Comment: @guardio yes it is exact code and working in demo but above code is not showing same result in my page. can you run this code at your end as well

Comment: check your console the problem is in your other code not the sample snippet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `in_array`

```
<input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|12' id="A11"  <?php if(in_array("A11", $seatdata)){echo "checked";}?> />
```